# Web scraping withe BeautifulSoup and unfound content

Tags: python, html, http, beautifulsoup, urllib2

I'm trying to make a basic web scraper using BeautifulSoup in Python. However my target page is making it difficult.

When I make the request, I get a response with the HTML. However in the body, it only displays 1 div as:

```
'<div id="miniwidget" style="width:100%; height:100%;"></div>'
```

I've navigated through the websites HTML in Google Chrome, but I'm new enough to this to not exactly understand why the page doesn't generate all of the content within that div.

How would I go about making a request that would generate the rest of the HTML?

Here's what I've written:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

def Call_Webpage(url):
  html = urlopen(url)
  bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html, features="html.parser")
   soup = bsObj.body.findAll('div')
   print(soup)
```

Response:

```
<div id="miniwidget" style="width:100%; height:100%;"></div>
```

Comment: It sounds like the content might be loaded dynamically using JavaScript. If that is the case you wont be able to use BeautifulSoup to scrape the website and will need to use something else like Selenium.

Comment: Honestly, I had a feeling it was but was really hoping not. I'll give that a try.

Comment: Did you check whether the content is dynamically generated? Also, variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Comment: Yes, it was discovered that the content is dynamically generated.

Answer (score 0):

depends what you want to find on that page...
e.g. for inspecting meta tags you would use soup.find_all('meta') etc.

you also could do

```
    request = urllib.request.Request(domain_url, None, headers)
    result = urllib.request.urlopen(request,timeout=timeout)
    resulttext = result.read()
```

to get the whole page as text